# Start footnote counter at 1

Tags: footnotes, counters, footmisc

I'm using symbols for footnotes in my document but I want the footnotes to start with the dagger, and not the asterisk. Is there a way to change the default starting counter for the footnotes so that it always starts at 1 (dagger) for each new page? `\setcounter{footnote}{1}` doesn't seem to work

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}

\begin{document}

I'd like the footnote to start with a dagger by default\footnote{but it's an asterisk} without having to specify \verb|\footnote[1]{the number}|

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: While you're obviously free to upvote all answers you find useful immediately, the site guidelines strongly encourage users to wait a few hours, and maybe even a day or more, before "accepting" the answer they find is best. For by "accepting" the very first answer that's been provided more or less immediately, users may actually be discouraging other would-be answer providers from providing their alternative, and quite possibly even better, solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This use case is described in the perpage [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bigfoot/perpage.pdf) on the first page:

> `\MakePerPage[2]{footnote}`
>
> will start footnote numbers with 2 on each page (the optional argument defaults to 1). 2 might be a strange number, unless you have used something like
>
> `\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}`
>
> and want to start off with a dagger.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage[2]{footnote}

\begin{document}

I'd like the footnote to start with a dagger by default\footnote{but it's an asterisk}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `footmisc` package provides the option `perpage` natively -- no need to load the `perpage` *package*. The `footmisc` package also lets you define your own preferred sequence of symbols to be used as footnote markers. For instance:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[perpage,symbol*]{footmisc}
%% Hopefully, your document has no pages with more than 9 footnotes:
\DefineFNsymbols*{namedisp}{{$\dagger$}{$\ddagger$}\S%
                            \P{$\Vert$}*{$\dagger\dagger$}%
                            {$\ddagger\ddagger$}{**}}
\setfnsymbol{namedisp}
\begin{document}

.\footnote{a} .\footnote{b} .\footnote{c} 
.\footnote{d} .\footnote{e} .\footnote{f} 
.\footnote{g} .\footnote{h} .\footnote{i} 
\end{document}
```